# set a function as label in a menuitem in python

Tags: python, gtk3

I am trying to set a function as label in a `MenuItem` in Python(gtk). I want to change the label of `MenuItem` every time the function is called.

As per the documentation - https://developer.gnome.org/pygtk/stable/class-gtkmenuitem.html#constructor-gtkmenuitem, label of a `MenuItem` must be string. How can I accomplish this?

```
   item5 = Gtk.MenuItem('Force Quit')
   item5.connect("activate", self.run_command4)
   item6 = Gtk.MenuItem('Sleep')
```

What I want is :

```
   a = os.path.basename(active_window_name)
   item5 = Gtk.MenuItem('Force Quit' + a)
```

"active_window_name" is the return of a function that is called every time the menu is created.As mentioned above, `('Force Quit' + a)` is not a valid label for `MenuItem`.

EDIT

`print(type(a)` gives `<type 'str'>`.

Also, the  code is  Ubuntu Budgie applet.

In PyCharm I have `code 0` when I run the applet but the applet does not load in the panel when I add it.

TRACEBACK

```
/usr/bin/python3.7 "/home/christoforos/Documents/Apple Menu New/applemenunew.py"

(applemenunew.py:5061): Gtk-WARNING **: 19:21:17.967: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:4:11: 'height' is not a valid property name

(applemenunew.py:5061): dbind-WARNING **: 19:21:18.114: Couldn't register with accessibility bus: Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: @theGtknerd the function is not in above snippet.Calling it I get the name of the active window in the screen.What I want is to change the label "Force Quit' with 'Force Quit 'and the name of the active window every time.

Comment: @cgiannakidis To achieve that, you will have to connect to some signal that is emitted whenever the active window changes, and change the label in that signal handler.

Comment: You need to cast the `a` window name to a string by using `str(a)`.

Comment: @theGtknerd thank you for your comment, but casting to a string with str() does not  solve the problem.

Comment: Your example `item5 = Gtk.MenuItem('Force Quit' + a)` works for me as expected. [Edit] your question and show the output of `print(type(a))` and add the **Full Traceback**

Comment: @cgiannakidis: Thats **not** a Traceback, these are `Gtk-WARNING`. Therefore i could **not** imagin that `.MenuItem('Force Quit' + a)` will lead to this `WARNING`. You are asking for problem **A** but have problem **B**. Without a [mcve] ther ist not help possible.